# Integration of following integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

Please help to solve the following integral
$\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-\theta x}(1-e^{-\theta x})^{c-1}[-\log(1-(1-e^{-\theta x})^{c-1})]^{\alpha-1}[1-(1-e^{-\theta x})^c]^{\frac{1}{\beta}-1}dx$. Hints on the method of approach is highly appreciated.

Comment: You could try using WolframAlpha.

Comment: I tried but failed to get the solution

Comment: Your brackets have not been placed properly.